# Convert 24 hour format to MySQL DATETIME format

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to convert 24 hour format time to datetime format so I can store it in Mysql as Datetime. I tried google but all the results come as other way around. For example, how to convert 21:30 to datetime format?

Comment: Why don't you use the standard SQL `TIMESTAMP` data type instead?

Comment: Table is already created. I don't have access to change it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MySQL DATETIME column stores both date and time, not just a time, and you don't **ever** format as string for sending to the database. Use a `PreparedStatement` to prevent [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Examples 1:

```
Date now = new Date();

String sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable ( MyDateTime ) VALUES ( ? )";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(now.getTime()));
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Examples 2:

```
String dateText = "11/8/2015 1:35 PM";
Date dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy h:mm a").parse(dateText);

String sql = "UPDATE MyTable SET MyDateTime = ? WHERE MyId = ?";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(dateTime.getTime()));
    stmt.setInt(2, 1234);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the java.util.Date, define the time you want and the use the constructor of java.sql.Date and in the parameter use the function .getTime(), like this:

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

The java.sql.Date, only uses the day, month and year, if you want with hours, minutes and seconds, you use a second variable wich is of type java.sql.Time:

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Time sqlDate = new java.sql.Time(utilDate.getTime());
```